# Router shuts down when clicking on "port forwarding"

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

This is a new router, and I had it set up working fine. Connected to a hub that connects two other computers. I had set up port forwarding for one port where I want a program running on remote computers to connect to a program I have (Port Any -> xxxx, directed to one of the computers). Don't think that is relevant, but still.

So problem is, when I now go into the router setup, and click on "port forwarding" tab, it does not open, just waits for 10-20 seconds, then the router restarts. This happens now every time.

What may this indicate..?

http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/871/screenshot2012040521510.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the configuration or the device itself are faulty. I would start with a factory reset of the device (often this means holding the reset button during powering-on and/or holding it for 10s). See if this helps. Obviously, you lose all the configuration.

And if that does not help - consider the router broken and have it replaced...

Comment: If a reset doesn't fix it try checking for a firmware update before considering it broken.